# Primefaces Mobile JS loading only on first 'page'

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a web app built using Primefaces mobile. On the whole everything works great, I can navigate happily from view to view etc.

The problem is coming when I try to load external JS files. More specifically the external JS / event listener is only working on the first 'view' that is loaded. All the other 'views' are acting as if the JS wasn't even being called.

Its taken me a couple of hours to narrow it down but I finally used a 3rd party library 'iscroll.js' (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to isolate the problem.

If I place the iscroll.js file in my resources directory and follow the iscroll docs, create a scrolling div on the first view everything works perfectly as expected. If I take the identical div and place it on any other view I get nothing. I can navigate back and forth through the 'views' and the initial 'view' maintains its 'correctness' (ie.it doesn't stop working when I go to another 'view').

Obviously my question is how do I get it to work on all views? My guess is that this is down to my lack of understanding of how Primefaces Mobile works but any JSF, Primefaces, JS Gurus that might be able to help would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE: Basic stripped down code to explain.

```
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:pou="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
    contentType="text/html"
    renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE"
    xmlns:ez="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/ezcomp">

<pm:page title="iConsult">

    <f:facet name="postinit"> 
        <h:outputScript name="js/iscroll.js"/>
    </f:facet>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Variables -----------------------------------------------------------
        var myScroll; // Scrolling lib var

        function loadScroll() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
            }, 100);

        }
        window.addEventListener('load', loadScroll, false);
     </script>


<!-- Main View -->
    <pm:view id="main">
        <pm:header title="main page" swatch="b">
            <f:facet name="right">

            </f:facet>
        </pm:header>

        <pm:content>
           // If I place the iscroll div here it works
           // ...lots of code to do with the app
        </pm:content>

    </pm:view>

 <!-- Other View -->
    <pm:view id="view1">
        <pm:header title="view1" swatch="b">
            <f:facet name="right">

            </f:facet>
        </pm:header>

        <pm:content>
           // If I place the iscroll div here it doesn't works
           // ...lots of code to do with the app
        </pm:content>

    </pm:view>

  </pm:page>

</f:view>
```

Just to be clear this is not exclusive to iscroll. I am just using it as a reference but this is the case with ALL external JS files that I have tried.

Comment: can it be that you didn't include the plugin js in the right place (some base template) and instead your included it in some inner page ?

Comment: @Daniel Nope not using any templates. It's a single 'page' app with multiple views. Just adding a stripped down version of the code in the question for clarity.

Comment: not familiar with the mobile ... but , if you replace the `<f:view ` with `<html ` , remove the `<f:facet` and place the `<h:outputScript` and the `script` inside a `<h:head>`  ?

Comment: @Daniel No, that doesn't help. When the above code is rendered it renders normal <html> <head> tags anyway.